# Difference between the dedicated sql pool and dedicated sql pool inside the azure synapse analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Difference between the dedicated sql pool and dedicated sql pool inside the azure synapse analytics?

While provision the azure synapse analytics we will use the Azure storage layer gen2 ,as per the msdn the data will be stored in the azure storage gen2 but azure gen2 will use the hdfs features.so how the dfs feature will use the syanpse analytics?

Answer (score 1):

They both are the same thing. Either you can first create a Dedicated SQL pool and link it with Synapse Workspace, or you can first create the Synapse Workspace and then dedicated pool inside it.

A dedicated SQL pool offers T-SQL based compute and storage capabilities. After creating a dedicated SQL pool in your Synapse workspace, data can be loaded, modeled, processed, and delivered for faster analytic insight.

Apart from Dedicated SQL pool, Azure Synapse provide **Serverless SQL** and **Apache Spark pools**. Based on your requirement you can choose the appropriate.

**Serverless SQL pool is a query service over the data in your data lake**. It enables you to access your data through the following functionalities:

- A familiar T-SQL syntax to query data in place without the need to copy or load data into a specialized store.
- Integrated connectivity via the T-SQL interface that offers a wide range of business intelligence and ad-hoc querying tools, including the most popular drivers.

You will be directly passing the file path stored in Data Lake Gen2 in T-SQL statement. Refer example below:

```
select top 10 *
from openrowset(
    bulk 'https://pandemicdatalake.blob.core.windows.net/public/curated/covid-19/ecdc_cases/latest/ecdc_cases.csv',
    format = 'csv',
    parser_version = '2.0',
    firstrow = 2 ) as rows
```

For more related information, I recommend you to go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/query-data-lake-using-azure-synapse-serverless-sql-pools/).

Comment: While provision the azure synapse we have option to choose the Azure data lake gen2 but while provisioning the dedicated sql pool we wont get that option?

Comment: dedicated SQL pool and data lake are two separate storage services. You need to choose any one. While deploying the synapse, you need to either choose dedicated SQL pool or Data lake where the data will be stored.